# How to create a custom Seq with bounded type parameter in Scala?

Tags: scala, collections, types, factory

Consider the following working custom `Seq`:

```
class MySeq[B](val s: Seq[B]) 
extends Seq[B]
with GenericTraversableTemplate[B, MySeq]
with SeqLike[B, MySeq[B]] {
  override def companion = MySeq

  def iterator = s.iterator

  def apply(i: Int) = s(i)

  def length = s.length

  override def toString = s map { _.toString } mkString("\n")
}
object MySeq extends SeqFactory[MySeq] {
  implicit def canBuildFrom[B]: CanBuildFrom[Coll, B, MySeq[B]] =
       new GenericCanBuildFrom[B]
  def newBuilder[B] = new ListBuffer[B] mapResult (x => new MySeq(x.toSeq))
}
```

I would like to impose a bound on the type parameter `B`. In other words, I would like something like this (not working):

```
class MyA

class MySeq[+B <: MyA](val s: Seq[B]) 
extends Seq[B]
with GenericTraversableTemplate[B, MySeq]
with SeqLike[B, MySeq[B]] {
  override def companion = MySeq  // Type Mismatch Here

  def iterator = s.iterator

  def apply(i: Int) = s(i)

  def length = s.length

  override def toString = s map { _.toString } mkString("\n")
}
object MySeq extends SeqFactory[MySeq] {
  implicit def canBuildFrom[B]: CanBuildFrom[Coll, B, MySeq[B]] =
       new GenericCanBuildFrom[B]
  // Type Mismatch in the line below
  def newBuilder[B] = new ListBuffer[B] mapResult (x => new MySeq(x.toSeq))
}
```

But I get the following type mismatch errors in the indicated lines:

```
inferred type arguments [B] do not conform to 
class MySeq's type parameter bounds [+B <: MyA] 
Main.scala  line 49

type mismatch;  
found   : countvotes.structures.MySeq.type  
required: scala.collection.generic.GenericCompanion[Seq]    
Main.scala  line 36

type mismatch;  
found   : MySeq[B(in class MySeq)]  
required: MySeq[B(in method newBuilder)]    
Main.scala  line 49

type mismatch;  
found   : scala.collection.immutable.Seq[B(in method newBuilder)]  
required: Seq[B(in class MySeq)]    
Main.scala  line 49
```

I have tried to solve this problem by adding bounds to the type parameters of CanBuildFrom and newBuilder, but then I get other error messages.

How can I create a custom `Seq` with a type parameter bound?

Comment: Any reason you're extending the collection rather then encapsulating it in a wrapper class with the upper bound requirement?

Comment: The reason is that it would be more elegant. I will use `map` and `filter` a lot on this class, and it would be inconvenient to manually unwrap and re-wrap every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not getting the error on line 26:

```
override def companion = MySeq
```

Maybe something else is causing that.

Anyway, the issue is that you cannot have a `GenericCompanion[MySeq]` (a supertype of `SeqFactory`). The reason is that `GenericCompanion[Coll]` means that you can construct a `Coll[A]` for any `A` (see signature of `newBuilder`). You also cannot have `MySeq[A] <: GenericTraversableTemplate[A, MySeq]`, because `genericBuilder` is impossible. This makes sense; `MySeq` isn't really a "generic collection" because it wants its elements to all be `MyA`.

The solution is to have `MySeq[B] <: GenericTraversableTemplate[B, Seq]`, (which comes free with `extends Seq`). You then have two choices for `companion`. It can just be the default one from `Seq`, or it can be `s.companion`. In the first case, `((as: MySeq[A]): Seq[A]).map(...)` will produce a `List` (at runtime; at compiletime it's just a generic `Seq`). In the second, it will depend on what `as.s` is (again, at runtime; compiletime will only see a `Seq`). You can keep the `extends SetLike`, though.

Then, you need to provide a custom `CanBuildFrom`: `MySeq.canBuildFrom[A <: MyA]: CanBuildFrom[MySeq[A], A, MySeq[A]]`, and define `MySeq#newBuilder`.

```
class MySeq[+B <: MyA](val s: Seq[B]) 
  extends Seq[B]
  with SeqLike[B, MySeq[B]]
{
  override def iterator = s.iterator
  override def apply(i: Int) = s(i)
  override def length = s.length

  override def toString = s.map(_.toString).mkString("\n")

  override def companion = s.companion
  protected[this] override def newBuilder: mutable.Builder[B, MySeq[B]] = new mutable.Builder[B, MySeq[B]] {
    private[this] val base = s.genericBuilder[B]
    override def +=(elem: B) = { base += elem; this }
    override def clear() = base.clear()
    override def result() = new MySeq[B](base.result())
  }
}

object MySeq {
  implicit def canBuildFrom[A <: MyA]: CanBuildFrom[MySeq[_], A, MySeq[A]] = ???
}

val list = List(new MyA, new MyA, new MyA, new MyA)
val vect = list.toVector
val mLst = new MySeq(list)
val mVec = new MySeq(vect)
{
  val res = mLst.filter(_.hashCode != list.head.hashCode)
  implicitly[res.type <:< MySeq[MyA]]
}
{
  val res = (mVec: Seq[MyA]).map(identity)
  assert(res.isInstanceOf[Vector[_]])
}
{
  val res = (mLst: Seq[MyA]).map(identity)
  assert(res.isInstanceOf[List[_]])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full MWE based on HTNW's accepted answer above, with `canBuildFrom` implemented:

```
class MyA

class MySeq[+A <: MyA](val s: Seq[A]) 
  extends Seq[A]
  with SeqLike[A, MySeq[A]]
{
  override def iterator = s.iterator
  override def apply(i: Int) = s(i)
  override def length = s.length

  override def toString = s.map(_.toString).mkString("\n")

  override def companion = s.companion
  protected[this] override def newBuilder = MySeq.newBuilder
}

object MySeq {
  def newBuilder[A <: MyA] = new mutable.Builder[A, MySeq[A]] {
    private[this] val base = Seq.newBuilder[A]
    override def +=(elem: A) = { base += elem; this }
    override def clear() = base.clear()
    override def result() = new MySeq[A](base.result())
  }

  implicit def canBuildFrom[A <: MyA]: CanBuildFrom[MySeq[_], A, MySeq[A]] = new CanBuildFrom[MySeq[_], A, MySeq[A]] {
    def apply(from: Election[_]) = newBuilder
    def apply() = newBuilder
  }
}
```